# Docker images are not persistent anymore/are disappearing after running "docker system prune". How to make them persistent again?

Tags: linux, docker

Someone in my lab ran a "docker system prune" command because he needed more space to download a large data set. However, after running it, new images, that are not being used, disappear after a minute or so. There must be a container using the image to make it persistent. We wanted to restart the docker daemon, but we can't right now because important containers are running (e.g. training deep neural networks). How to make the docker images persistent again? We are not sure if this colleague ran other commands that may have contributed to this situation. If this is relevant, we are using docker 18.09.6.

Comment: Prune removes only dangling images, not actual images. Your colleague probably executed other command that resulted in this situation.

Comment: Could you give any ideas of which commands result in this situation?

Comment: `docker system prune -a` would kill off any unused images, but it sounds like these images keep disappearing so unless they are running that command on a schedule every few minutes, it's not the culprit.

Comment: Update: we ran the same command (docker system prune) on another computer and we reproduced the scenario. Now the images are not persistent anymore.

Comment: Did anyone get a solution to this? .. I'm stuck here!

Answer (score 0):

From the docker documentation of [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)-

```
Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

$ docker system prune

WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all build cache
```

The -a option if added -a removes all unused images not just dangling ones. Hence if you want to persist with those images, you should avoid -a option. Looks like "-a" was indeed used which removed the unused images.